# JAVA: I have the address; how can I print its contents?

Tags: java

THE SHORT VERSION: I have an address; how can I print the contents at that address?

LONG VERSION: I have this object, and the object has two fields - dest and source.  The source is given to me as an address:

```
 Field Detail
 dest
 public final VVarRef dest
 The variable/register to store the value into.

 source
 public final VMemRef source
 The memory location being read.
```

I need to know what's at that address.

Comment: The question was probably downvoted because it lacks the obviosuly essential information about what those classes you're working with are, which makes it impossible to give a useful answer except mine, which was promptly criticized and downvoted as not usefulo enough.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I was always under the impression that a shorter question = better.

Comment: shorter is better, but it still needs to contain the necessary information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the definition/documentation of the class `VMemRef`.

**Update:** 
Accodring to the API doc link, the class `VMemRef` has two nested subclasses, `VMemRef.Global` and `VMemRef.Stack`. So you have to identify which one it is using `instanceof`, cast to that class and use its specific conent.

Comment: aint this more appropriate as a comment? looking at your reputation, you sure have the privilege of writing a comment.

Comment: I did...http://cs.ucla.edu/classes/spring11/cs132/kannan/vapor-parser/vapor-parser-javadoc/cs132/vapor/ast/VMemRef.html.  Not sure how to use the information....Say the object name is `c`.  Do I do `c.source.xxxx`?

Comment: @Mukul Goel: it's the only answer possible given the lack of information.

Comment: Yea, I agree with you, That is why mentioning it in comments and prompting OP for more info would have been a better approach. Anyways I have removed my Downvote after your _Update:_